# Tiny star like dots appearing in the varnish

Tags: varnishing

I am trying to high gloss varnih the Oak bed to my old Chevy truck, I removed the bed from the truck sanded it back to wood, the bed is only 4 years old, starting with 80 grit then 120 the 240 and finally wire wool I then hoovered it and wipe down with thinners and let dry,I then varnished the planks in the morning and left them until the next morning to apply the next coats I am now on the 4th coat, I notice these tiny star light dots in the varnish the dots are about the size of a pin head or smaller and you can see them reflecting in the light like stars, the planks are smooth if you run your hands over them, I think it might be tiny dust particles but I can see how as its being varnished in our spare room, anyone have any idears what this might be.

Comment: A picture would be very helpful.

Comment: It almost sounds like bubbles, are you lightly sanding between coats I use 400+ that may be overkill here. But you do need to buff the surface prior to the next coat.

Comment: While I agree it's likely dust or bubbles, if you are using a water based varnish, with some woods you need to seal the wood first.  Failure to do so can have tannins and oils seep into the varnish from the wood itself, which can ruin the finish (typically over time, and probably not in the way you're describing)